# How can I close a specific Xcode project, from the command line, without Applescript?

Tags: xcode, command-line

I'd like to close a specific Xcode project from the command line without closing any other projects (so I can't just use `kill`). Applescript is problematic in Catalina because of additional permissions needed. Is there any other way to do what I want?

Comment: Any particular reason you'd expect that any other language wouldn't be subject to the same security restrictions in Catalina? Why not take the same avenue other applications with similar functionality have and instruct users on how to grant access to your script/application to enable this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bring the requested project to front and close the front window

```
$ xed .
$ osascript -e 'tell app "XCode" to close window 0'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the Terminal to control other apps via AppleScript, you must give permission. But this is not difficult, because the system will prompt for the needed permission if you have not given it already.

For example, I just said

```
 $ osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to close window 1'
```

and I saw this dialog:

[image]

I clicked OK and the window closed, as ordered. No problem. So you'd see something like that for Xcode, you'd grant permission, and that would be that. The permission is recorded in the Security & Privacy pref pane under Automation.

If you prefer to pass thru System Events, the permission is recorded under Accessibility. Note that *that* is a permission you can grant in advance. But you still need to go thru the dialog so you can give Terminal permission to talk to System Events.

If you deny access in the dialog and you want to be asked again, use `tccutil` to reset the database. Good discussion here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/384230/how-do-i-reset-screen-recording-permission-on-macos-catalina